# How to authenticate Oauth with REST implementations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following scenario,

I have a Rails app for developers that authenticates with devise. The app also responds like a rest API i.e.

```
/photos.json  # brings all photos from the logged user.
```

My question is how can I implement in this case a 2-legged OAuth restful strategy between the user and the app while keeping the devise as main authentication method. I'm a little lost here.

I'm aware there's `token_authenticatable` in Devise but somehow I think that authenticating only with a simple token is not secure enough?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full blown OAuth implementation check out https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable