# How to access create method of a Rails controller using REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a rails application which has a model named `Product` having two field named `product_name`, `product_price`. Devise gem is also used for authentication. Email and password is the two credentials for login.

How can I create a product using **REST**? What will be the URL structure?

Thanks

My web application is fully functional. I want to create an API to access this application from another website. I want to provide an URL, in which a person will click and a product will be created in my site.

Provided that person is registered. So my main question is, how can I send authentication, post, product_name, product_price such requests through URL to the create action.

Comment: For protected API access you should create an OAuth authentication system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840978/how-to-authenticate-oauth-with-rest-implementations

Answer (score 0):

```
# Models:

class User
  has_many :products
end
class Product
  belongs_to :user
end

# Routes:

resources :user  # Access stuff individually
resources :product
resources :user do # or nested, e.g. user/:id/product/:id   
  resources :product
end

# type rake rake routes to see the paths you can use. 

# Forms can use, e.g. for product for a given user 
<%= form_for ([@user,@product]) do |p| %>

# Links can be of the form 
<%= link_to 'Add User', new_user_path %>
```